# Should calculations be repeated in if statements?

Tags: php, if-statement

If a calculation is used in the evaluation expression of an `if` statement and then again in the execution statement(s), is it more or less efficient to perform the calculation twice or to introduce a new variable?

In other words, is

```
if ($x <> some_complex_calculation()) {
    ...
    $x = some_complex_calculation();
}
```

better than this:

```
$result = some_complex_calculation();
if ($x <> $result) {
    ...
    $x = $result;
}
```

Or, is this:

```
if ($x <> get_something_from_database()) {
    ...
    $x = get_something_from_database();
}
```

better than this:

```
$result = get_something_from_database();
if ($x <> $result) {
    ...
    $x = $result;
}
```

Comment: do the calculation once

Comment: All of the above can be simplified to `$x = some_complex_calculation();`, the conditional does not make any sense in those lines.

Comment: You're right, @arkascha.  A conditional doesn't make sense for the code I presented.  I used a simple example to illustrate my question, and I've added `...` to the code to indicate that the assignment is "a" statement, not "the only" statement, for execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it will always be more efficient to save the results of the calculation, no matter how trivial it may be, so if that is all you care about using a temporary is the only "correct" option.

That said, the performance aspect would only be important if the calculation takes up a sizeable amount of your total running time, which is unusual in practice. On the other hand, there are other considerations that can influence or even dictate your decision:

**Correctness**: If you do the calculation twice there is the possibility that the application state will have changed between the two calculations. So you would enter a branch because e.g. `get_something() > 5` but then inside the branch it could be that `get_something() <= 5` because someone else has modified the data in the meantime. Does it matter to you? How do you want the app to behave in this case? These are questions far more important than "is it going to run faster".

**Understandability:** Whenever I see a variable being defined, I usually have to allocate a "mental slot" to tracking that variable and its usages until I have figured out how the function it is defined in works as a whole. If the code is using too many temporaries then the cognitive load to the reader is increased. Does it matter to you? What is the relative impact vs the performance difference?

Answer (score 0):

If the calculation has different arguments at each call and thus different results, then you will need to call it each time. For example:

```
function add( a, b ) 
{
   return a + b;
}
```

And called like so:

```
if( add( 1, 2) > a )
else if ( add( 4,5 ) > c )
```

This would return different values each time so you would need to compute it in the if.

However if it is the same comparison value each time, it better to store the result if used more than once:

```
result = add(5, 6)

if( result > 10 ) 
else if( result > 12 )
```